# Display digit in digital form(digital clock)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am building an application in iphone for that I need to draw a 7-bit segment display which will display the numbers that is being fed by the user.I am using CGPath and CGcontext.
I have drawn 7-bit segment as the no in digital clock.But, I am not getting the way to display  the no given By user. To draw a 7-bit segment display, i have done..

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   
    CGLineCap cap =kCGLineCapRound;
    center = CGPointMake(120, 130.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5);
    path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 08.0);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, cap);
    CGPoint aOnePoint=CGPointMake(center.x ,center.y);
    CGPoint aTwoPoint=CGPointMake(center.x ,center.y+30);
    CGPoint points[]= {aOnePoint,aTwoPoint};    

    CGAffineTransform translation1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 30);  
    CGAffineTransform translation2 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(translation1, 0, 42);
    CGAffineTransform translation3 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(translation1, 42,0); 
    CGAffineTransform translation4 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(translation1, 42, 42);
    CGAffineTransform translation7 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-270, 0); 
    CGAffineTransform translation5 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2.0);
    CGAffineTransform translation8 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-4, +3);
    CGAffineTransform translation6 = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(translation7, translation5),translation8);
    CGAffineTransform translation9 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(translation6, -44, 0);
    CGAffineTransform translation10 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(translation6,-86, 0);

    CGPathAddLines(path, &translation1 ,points,2);
    CGPathAddLines(path, &translation2,points,2);
    CGPathAddLines(path, &translation3 ,points,2);
    CGPathAddLines(path, &translation4 ,points,2);
    CGPathAddLines(path, &translation6 ,points,2);
    CGPathAddLines(path, &translation9 ,points,2);
    CGPathAddLines(path, &translation10 ,points,2);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGPathRelease(path);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could also use a custom font: http://www.dafont.com/ds-digital.font

Comment: But i don't have to use custom font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to draw it? I'm sure 10 images, one for each numeral, would be much more satisfying.

*Edit from comment:*
If you name your images `0.png` `1.png` `2.png` etc., you can use the integer value entered by the user to change the displayed image(s) very quickly. If you're worried about wasting disk space, it is really not a problem, as each image should not weigh more than 5kB if well compressed.

Comment: No, i need to draw a path for numeral 0 and after that based on the numeral input i need to change that path. I don't need 10 images.

Comment: I reckon you could get a better design with images, and if you name your images 0.png 1.png 2.png etc., you can use the integer value to switch the displayed image very quickly. If you're worried about wasting disk space, it is really not a problem, as each image should not weigh more than 5kB if well compressed. But it's up to you ;)

Comment: thnx Buddy, i will now switch to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

even more efficient, why don't you just use a label with a [digital font](http://www.1001fonts.com/digital-fonts.html). This will save you a lot of work and will give you a lot of flexibility and control. below is a simple example

```
timerDisplay = Label::createWithTTF("00:00:00", "fonts/digital-7.ttf", 32);
timerDisplay->setPosition(Point((visibleSize.width -
timerDisplay->getContentSize().width)/2, visibleSize.height));
timerDisplay->setAlignment(TextHAlignment::CENTER);
this->addChild(timerDisplay);
```